# Parse.com Facebook Login with Ionic Framework

Tags: parse-platform, facebook-javascript-sdk, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a problem with an Ionic Framework app that uses Parse.com's Facebook Login.

I have followed the instructions on the Parse.com website (https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#fbusers-setup) and have had no luck, spent the entire day on it today.

The code I have in my app.js

```
Parse.initialize('xxxxxx', 'xxxxx');
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
//     FB.init({
//   appId      : 'xxxxxxxx',
//   status     : true,
//   xfbml      : true,
//   version    : 'v2.0'
// });
Parse.FacebookUtils.init({
  appId: 'xxxxxx',
  cookie: true,
  status: true,
  useCachedDialogs: false,
  logging: true,
  oauth: true
});
};

(function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
$rootScope.user = null;
$rootScope.loggedIn = false;
if (currentUser) {
$rootScope.user = currentUser;
$rootScope.loggedIn = true;
}
$rootScope.userActionText = $rootScope.loggedIn ? 'Sign out' : 'Create account';
});
```

The settings I have on the FB app:

**Basic Settings:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/3c6vib6i323bbvf/Basic.png?dl=0

**Advanced Settings:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/f5q3rgh7v014ohf/Advanced.png?dl=0

I use the iOS Simulator and ran the app on the device. After tapping "Login with Facebook" it goes to a "browser" type of screen and shows the following error:

**Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.**

I have tried:

1. Every single Google result with the error message and relevant results
2. Adding in channel URL's hosting on myapp.parseapp.com/channel.html
3. Using the FB.init method that is commented out
4. Changing up the FB App settings from localhost to a online domain
5. Different variations of the init key:val

Does anyone have experience with Parse.com and Ionic Framework who could shed some light on what I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: have you figured it out yet? What's your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use plugins ( Facebook and Parse ) or maybe try https://www.parse.com/questions/facebook-with-cordovaphonegap (I think he only used Facebook Plugin) there is couple of Parse plugin or just create yours.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your domain in your Facebook settings > Basic > App Domains

Then you also need to add it in your Website URL to match in your App Domains.

I think `parseapp.com` is the domain of the apps of Parse.com.